# pytest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, while executing through jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, pytest, jenkins-plugins, ui-automation, python-3.8

I am trying to run python test through jenkins. I have pytest framework.
I have also installed python 3.8 on jenkins slave machine and set path in the environment variables

I have added below path under PATH section of environment variable as below
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

But still I am getting below error on while running job.

Below are my windows batch command to run from Jenkins:

```
echo '#### Create Virtual Environment ####'
python -m venv .UIAutomation/venv
echo '#### Activate Virtual Environment ####'


echo '#### Run tests ####'
pytest -s -v --alluredir=.UIAutomation/reports ./UIAutomation/tests --env=staging --browser=chrome
```

Please help

More details about console error :
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

12:04:12     Error: pg_config executable not found.
pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory

Note:
Below is my first requirement from file
Collecting psycopg2==2.8.6 (from -r ./UIAutomation/requirements.txt

So after execution I am seeing below error at first line of console-
12:04:12     Error: pg_config executable not found.
12:04:12     pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory

Comment: Yes, pytest is part of requirement @john-hen

Comment: from your screenshot the installation of your dependencies is failing

Comment: Yes, but what can be root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, I find the batch `call` suspicious.
I think call launches a new console and returns to the script, if its done. So in your case, you activate your `venv` in another console and then use your standard python `env`, not the `venv` and there is no `pytest` dependency installed.

See also: https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

I had a similiar problem in a `yaml` script I wrote for Azure DevOps.
I did solve that, with creating the venv and then adding the `venv` path to the environment variables.

Comment: is there any suggestions or solution. If question is not clear , can you please ask what is not clear in comment. Thanks